# Create Background Color CSS3 Animations after Background Image Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create background-color CSS3 Keyframe animations after the first animation which is a background image. I am not able to create another animation after the text animation fades. After the text animation fades, I would like the background's opacity to turn to 0.3 and once again fade in text. Below is what I have.

Please see full code here: codepen:https://codepen.io/imdaone/pen/JJrYyV

```
.background {
  width: 80%;
  height: 220px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(imgs/ad-ex.png) no-repeat top left;
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: move 5s 1 linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}
```

Comment: Format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to attempt to do animations with sequences.  If I am not wrong, you cannot do it with pure css.  You might want to venture into using some javascript animation library where it can handle sequencial animation.

You can still use vanilla js but i think its more tedious just to achieve what you want